# Connect two strokeEnd animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, swift3

I am trying to make a custom activity indicator similar to the Android material design circular indeterminate activity indicator. Basically I want to draw the circle two times and erase it, but erasing and drawing does not happen at the same time or speed. This is what I have so far:

```
let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red().cgColor
progressLayer.fillColor = nil
progressLayer.lineWidth = 2

let drawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
drawAnimation.duration = duration / 2
drawAnimation.fromValue = 0
drawAnimation.toValue = 1
drawAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

let eraseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
eraseAnimation.duration = duration / 2
eraseAnimation.beginTime = 0.2
eraseAnimation.fromValue = 0
eraseAnimation.toValue = 0.4
eraseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
eraseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

let endDrawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
endDrawAnimation.beginTime = duration / 2
endDrawAnimation.duration = duration / 2
endDrawAnimation.fromValue = 0
endDrawAnimation.toValue = 1
endDrawAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
endDrawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

let endEraseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
endEraseAnimation.beginTime = duration / 2
endEraseAnimation.duration = duration / 4
endEraseAnimation.fromValue = 0.4
endEraseAnimation.toValue = 1
endEraseAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
endEraseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

let endEraseAnimation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
endEraseAnimation2.beginTime = duration * 3 / 4
endEraseAnimation2.duration = duration / 4
endEraseAnimation2.fromValue = 0
endEraseAnimation2.toValue = 1
endEraseAnimation2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
endEraseAnimation2.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards


let animations = CAAnimationGroup()
animations.duration = duration
animations.animations = [drawAnimation, eraseAnimation, endDrawAnimation, endEraseAnimation, endEraseAnimation2]
animations.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
animations.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
progressLayer.add(animations, forKey: "stroke")
```

The code does everything as expected, except for one issue. When the first `strokeEnd` animation is done and the second one starts there is sort of a flash meaning the part of the circle that was drawn till that point disappears and then drawing starts again from 0. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Your code show errors when I try to compile, please put your real code, in order to help you

Comment: @ReinierMelian this is Swift 3 code, make sure you're using Xcode 8 or translate it to Swift 2.  @Banana, what is `progressLayer`?

Comment: `progressLayer` is a `CAShapeLayer`, I added this to the question above.

Comment: @Banana, could you please post a `.gif` of what you want and what you actually get, so that it is easier to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

> When the first strokeEnd animation is done and the second one starts
>   there is sort of a flash meaning the part of the circle that was drawn
>   till that point disappears and then drawing starts again from 0.

If you compare the setup of both `drawAnimation` and `endDrawAnimation` you will see that they are identical except for the `beginTime` property. That is what causes your flickering. They both start at 0 and they both end with 1. Since you have not specified the desired outcome I can just assume that you want `endDrawAnimation` to have a `fromValue` of 1.

```
let drawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
drawAnimation.duration = duration / 2
drawAnimation.fromValue = 0
drawAnimation.toValue = 1
drawAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
drawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

let endDrawAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
endDrawAnimation.beginTime = duration / 2 // Starts after the first animation and starts with 0 again.
endDrawAnimation.duration = duration / 2
endDrawAnimation.fromValue = 0
endDrawAnimation.toValue = 1
endDrawAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
endDrawAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

As far as I can see you want to create key frame animation meaning that you have predefined offsets at which the animation behaviour (speed, value, etc.) changes. You might want to consider using [`CAKeyframeAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/) instead.

I am unsure if you are aware of this but at the moment you have two animations running concurrently on `strokeStart`:

- `eraseAnimation` that starts at `0.2` with a duration of `0.5 * duration`
- `endEraseAnimation` that starts at `0.5 * duration`.

That means that the end of `eraseAnimation` (`0.2 + 0.5 * duration`) is always greater than the start of `endEraseAnimation` (`0.5 * duration`)